# Method resolution order and metaclasses

Tags: python, metaclass, method-resolution-order

How come a metaclass does not show up in the MRO?

For instance:

```
>>> class Foo(type):
...  foo = 21
... 
>>> class Bar(metaclass=Foo):
...  pass
... 
>>> Bar.mro()
[<class '__main__.Bar'>, <class 'object'>]
>>> Bar.foo
21
```

Also, I saw elsewhere that Python uses C3 linearization to compute the MRO, but this linearization does not handle metaclasses. So what algorithm does Python use in that case?

Comment: Have you tried calling it on an instance of Bar? Because then it doesn't work. And AFAIK metaclasses & multiple inheritance isn't supported. However, I'm at a loss on how to get to Foo for the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because none of your classes *derive* from the metaclass. A metaclass is *not a base class*. The metaclass is the factory that *produced* the `Bar` class object, just like a class object produces instances.

There is no linearisation required here. `Bar` is an object of type `Foo`, just like other classes are of type `type`. Any subclasses of `Bar` will have the same type (the metaclass); they have that relationship *directly*. A class can have only **one** metaclass at a time.

A metaclass comes last when looking up attributes; so `Bar.spam` will first be looked for in the MRO, and only *then* on `type(Bar)`.

Of course, metaclasses use an inheritance hierarchy too; `Foo` was derived from `type` in your example. That relationship uses an MRO too.